# I have records in elasticserver, one of the field has a range type field but i cant get a query to get those records

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

this is one the records which have the salaryPerHours inside it

```
 "salaryPerHours" : {
            "gt" : 10.0,
            "gte" : 10.0,
            "lt" : 1.0E9,
            "lte" : 1.0E9
          },
```

and the query i am using in kibana console is

```
GET /UAT_SETUP/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "salaryPerHours": {
        "gt": 10.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

still it is not giving me the record

the mapping of this field is as follows

```
"salaryPerHours": {
            "type": "double_range"
          },
```

any suggestion, what is wrong with this query, i feel there is nothing wrong in the mappings

Answer (score 0):

It's working. Check if there are any typos. And check if there is any relation [defined](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html).

```
PUT test_double_range
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "salaryPerHours": {
        "type": "double_range"
      }
    }
  }
}
POST _bulk
{ "index":{"_index":"test_double_range"}}
{"salaryPerHours" : {"gt" : 10.0, "gte" : 10.0, "lt" : 1.0E9,"lte" : 1.0E9}}

GET /test_double_range/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "salaryPerHours": {
        "gt": 10.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```